# Qudpsocket class usage

Tags: c++, qt, qudpsocket

I am using QUdpSocket for reading multicast data coming on my machine 
My problem is that my machine has two Ethernet interfaces. One having network address 66.25.x.x and other 66.26.x.x
I want to read data on both Ethernet interfaces which is coming on port 64010 and multicast group 224.4.7.11.

How to specify which interface to read while joining multicast group in QUdpSocket to read data?
Thanks

Comment: There is [an overload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#joinMulticastGroup-1) which allows you to specify an interface

Comment: What platform are you on? I've looked into this on Windows 10, and it doesn't appear that you can do it.

Comment: I am on windows 7.